# Transforming multiple rows to one row

Tags: excel

I have a text data set that I need to reformat before I can use it. It's currently a text file that I've imported into Excel. Each record currently spans three rows but is in one column. I need to transform it so it's one row with three columns.

The sample below is how my data is currently structured. It shows three records out of 2,000+. The 'Row' column is just for reference and not actually in my data.

```
Row |      Column
 1  | File Number: 001
 2  | File Code: ABC
 3  | File Description: Text file
 4  | File Number: 002
 5  | File Code: DEF
 6  | File Description: Text file
 7  | File Number: 003
 8  | File Code: GHI
 9  | File Description: Text file
```

Just to clarify, row 1 to 3 would be one record. Row 4 to 6 would be the second record. The third record is from row 7 to 9. Every record in my data is currently split into three rows.

I want to reformat it so it looks something like this:

```
Row | File Number | File Code | File Description
 1  |     001     |    ABC    |      Text
 2  |     002     |    DEF    |      Text
 3  |     003     |    GHI    |      Text
```

Again, the row column is just for reference and I don't need it in my reformatted data. Copy and pasting does not appear to be a good option.

Is there a quick way to transform this?

Comment: Sorry, I've removed the tag. I'm not sure what possible solutions are available for this questions. Hence, the usage of the excel-vba tag.

Comment: Wouldn't you still have to manually delete all the rows in between because shift cells only deletes those at the top? Given the number of records I have, I'm afraid I might run into misalignment issues...But this is still worth a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VBA to do this. Code like this might help you for this particular situation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    ' Let's make the tabular structure in column C, D and E
    '     C        D        E
    ' File Number Code  Description

    Dim CurrentRow As Integer
    CurrentRow = 2 ' Read from A2

    Dim WriteRow As Integer
    WriteRow = 2 ' Write to C2

    Do
        ' if we see empty data in column A, then we are done with our work
        If Len(Trim(Range("A" & CurrentRow))) = 0 Then Exit Do

        ' make 3 rows of data into 3 columns in a single row
        Range("C" & WriteRow).Value = Trim(Replace(Range("A" & CurrentRow).Text, "File Number:", ""))
        Range("D" & WriteRow).Value = Trim(Replace(Range("A" & CurrentRow + 1).Text, "File Code:", ""))
        Range("E" & WriteRow).Value = Trim(Replace(Range("A" & CurrentRow + 2).Text, "File Description:", ""))

        ' increment our reading and writing markers
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 3
        WriteRow = WriteRow + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Feel free to test out.

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me a lot of time. This worked very well. I didn't realize you could put excel formulas into vba code (mind you, I know next to nothing about vba). Your notes were helpful too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference: this uses TextToColumns, AutoFilter, and places results on a new sheet

```
Option Explicit

Sub mergeRows()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, fld As Variant, i As Long, cel As Range

   fld = Split("File Number,File Code,File Description", ",")
   Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
   Set ws = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With Worksheets(1)

      Set cel = .Range("A1")

      .UsedRange.Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=cel.Cells(1, 2), _
                                          DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                          Other:=True, OtherChar:=":"

      .Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      cel.Cells(0, 2) = "Col 1": cel.Cells(0, 3) = "Col 2"
      .UsedRange.AutoFilter

      For i = 0 To 2
         .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=cel.Cells(1, 2).Column, Criteria1:=fld(i)
         .UsedRange.Columns(cel.Cells(1, 3).Column).Copy ws.Cells(1, i + 1)
         ws.Cells(1, i + 1) = fld(i)
      Next

      .UsedRange.AutoFilter
      .UsedRange.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Delete
      cel.Cells(0, 2).EntireRow.Delete
   End With
   ws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```